# C# object cast to Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#

my method

```
parms.ValidationObject = new { validations = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { parms.JsonObjectName, modelValidations } } };
    return parms.ValidationObject;
```

where `ValidationObject` is `Object` Type

Later on I call this method

```
var modelValidations = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var validations = GetValidations(nextParms);
modelValidations = modelValidations.Concat(validations).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

but I get

> cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'

Simple cast to `Dictionary<string, object>` does not work. What can I do?

Comment: 1) `ValidationObject` is *not* a direct intance of `object`, as you say.  It is an *anonymous* type.  2) What is the return type of `GetValidations(nextParms)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't clear, but when you say "my method" is:

```
parms.ValidationObject = new { validations = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { parms.JsonObjectName, modelValidations } } };
    return parms.ValidationObject;
```

I assume you mean that the code above is the implementation to the method, `GetValidations`.  If so, then the  problem is that the return type of your method is probably `object` since it can't be the *real* type of `parms.ValidationObject`, since that is an anonymous type which can't leak out of the method.

So I think your real problem is that you are trying to consume the `validations` property defined *on that anonymous type* from an external method.  Really you should step back and stop doing this.  If you want to consume an anonymous type outside of the method in which it is declared, it means you've made a mistake.

Instead either use a `Tuple` variant to return the values you want, use `out` parameters, define a new concrete type altogether, or just return the dictionary (`parms.ValidationObject.validations`) itself -- it's entirely unclear why you're using an anonymous type here since you only define one property.  Under no circumstance should you try to interact with anonymous types in a static fashion outside of the method in which the type is declared.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast validations to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>>` before you pass it to `Concat` since that is what it expects.

Make this change as well:

```
parms.ValidationObject = new Dictionary<string, object>() { parms.JsonObjectName, modelValidations };
```

Comment: How do you know what the type of `validations` is?

Comment: because the OP said his method at the top returns it. And then he is trying to concatenate it with another dictionary and the error says that too. Your comment was helpful too about it not being a direct instance of dictionary.